# Issue building react native project in Xcode - error: could not find auto linked libraries + undefined symbols etc

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am trying to get a react native app running on my new Mac mini m1.

First time trying to get everything set up. So far it's been quite painful.

The error occurs when building in Xcode. Initially I had some other errors in Xcode which were resolved by editing the flipper version in the Podfile.

Now I have a list of unlinked libraries and undefined symbols in swift

[image]

My searches did suggest that adding an empty swift file might help but it hasn't made a difference

[image]

Any idea on what I can try next?

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember exactly but commenting out the flipper part in the Podfile seemed to fix the majority of the issues

````
  # use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.74.0' })
  # post_install do |installer|
# flipper_post_install(installer)
# end```
````